# Uncertainty regarding MTW Exercise 3.6 and 3.9

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity

I am currently working through the exercises in "Gravitation" by MTW. I am a little unsure about my approach to Exercise 3.6 and I feel stuck at Exercise 3.9:

Exercise 3.6 reads:

*An observer with 4-velocity $\boldsymbol{u}$ picks out three directions in spacetime that are orthogonal and purely spatial (no time part) as seen in his frame. Let **$\boldsymbol{e_{\hat{1}}}, \boldsymbol{e_{\hat{2}}}, \boldsymbol{e_{\hat{3}}}$** be unit vectors in those directions and let them be oriented in a righthanded way ($\boldsymbol{e_{\hat{1}}} \boldsymbol{\cdot}\boldsymbol{e_{\hat{2}}}\times\boldsymbol{e_{\hat{3}}} = + \ 1 $ in three-dimensional language). Why do the following relations hold?*

$$ \boldsymbol{e_{\hat{j}}}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\boldsymbol{u} = 0, \ \ \ \ \ \boldsymbol{e_{\hat{j}}}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\boldsymbol{e_{\hat{k}}} = \delta_{jk}$$

*What vectors are to be inserted in the two slots of the electromagnetic field tensor **Faraday** if one wants to get out the electric field along $\boldsymbol{e_{\hat{j}}}$?*

My answer to the first part of this exercise would be the following:

$ \boldsymbol{e_{\hat{j}}}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\boldsymbol{u} = 0 $ holds because the 4-velocity $\boldsymbol{u}$ in the observer's frame only has a time component $u^\alpha = (1,0,0,0)$, and the unit vectors are purely spatial, which is why their scalar product reduces to $0$ (i.e. $\boldsymbol{u}$ is orthogonal to all $\boldsymbol{e_{\hat{j}}}$).

$\boldsymbol{e_{\hat{j}}}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\boldsymbol{e_{\hat{k}}} = \delta_{jk}$ is true because the unit vectors $\boldsymbol{e_{\hat{j}}}$ are purely spatial, orthogonal and of unit length.

Is there a flaw in my argument?

For the second part, I would argue that given the **Faraday** tensor's components:

$$||F_{\alpha \beta}|| = \begin{Vmatrix}
0 & -E_x & -E_y & -E_z \\
E_x & 0 & B_z & -B_y \\
E_y & -B_z & 0 & B_x \\
E_z & B_y & -B_x & 0 
\end{Vmatrix}$$

to get the electric field along $ \boldsymbol{e_{\hat{j}}} $ one needs to insert the base vectors $\boldsymbol{e_{\hat{j}}}$ and $\boldsymbol{e_{\hat{0}}} = \boldsymbol{u}$:

$$E_j = \boldsymbol{F(\boldsymbol{e_{\hat{j}}}, \boldsymbol{u}}) $$

$$E_j= F_{j \beta} u^\beta $$

$$E_j= F_{j 0} $$.

In order to get the magnetic field components along $\boldsymbol{e_{\hat{j}}}$, we need to insert the respective two other unit vectors $\boldsymbol{e_{\hat{i}}}$ and $\boldsymbol{e_{\hat{k}}}$ in the correct order so as to respect their right-handedness (I am unsure about the correct notation here):

$$B_j = \epsilon_{jik} \boldsymbol{F(\boldsymbol{e_{\hat{i}}}, \boldsymbol{e_{\hat{k}}})} $$

$$B_j= \epsilon_{jik} F_{i k} $$

Here, $\epsilon_{jik}$ are the components of the Levi-Civita Tensor. So, for example in order to get $B_1$, insert $\boldsymbol{e_{\hat{2}}}$ and $\boldsymbol{e_{\hat{3}}}$ to get $F_{2 3} = B_x$.

Is this a valid approach to the given questions?

My second issue is with Exercise 3.9 (a), where I have the feeling I don't really understand the question itself:

*Justify the formula*

$$d(u_\mu v^\nu)/d\tau = (du_\mu/d\tau)v^\nu + u_\mu (dv^\nu /d\tau)$$
*by considering the special case $\mu = 0$, $\nu = 1$.*

It appears to me that this is simply the usual product rule of differentiation. I don't know how to start attacking this problem, because I fail to see the problem. Could anyone give me a hint what is to show here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you are correct.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any idea about my second question regarding Exercise 3.9 (a)?

Comment: I'd have to look in my copy of MTW for context but it appears to be the product rule, but for 4-vector inner produces on a manifold.  Not sure how much "justification" they are looking for.